# How to refresh ss-multiselect-dropdown based on input provided by user

Tags: angular, dropdown, multi-select

I have requirement to select multiple values from dropdown based on input selected in previous input.

e.g.:
Based on countries in select dropdown input, I want to display list of all states in selected country. user can select multiple states.

To Display list of countries, I have used

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" 
    formControlName="country" required>
    <option *ngFor='let country of countries' [value]="country._id">
        {{country.country_name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

To display States, I have used a multiselect dropdown control for my form in angular 6 using this package: https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect.

Code For Users.Componen.ts

---

```
    public stateControlSettings: IMultiSelectSettings = {
    enableSearch: true,
    checkedStyle: 'checkboxes',
    buttonClasses: 'btn btn-secondary btn-block',
    dynamicTitleMaxItems: 5,
    displayAllSelectedText: true
};

public stateControlTexts: IMultiSelectTexts = {
    checkAll: 'Select all',
    uncheckAll: 'Unselect all',
    checked: 'item selected',
    checkedPlural: 'items selected',
    searchPlaceholder: 'Find...',
    defaultTitle: 'Select state using search filter',
    allSelected: 'All selected',
};

public stateControlOptions: IMultiSelectOption[] = [];
public stateControlModel: number[];
```

---

Code for Users.Component.html

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown class="custom-multiselect" [options]="stateControlOptions"
[texts]="stateControlTexts" [settings]="stateControlSettings" [(ngModel)]="stateControlModel">
```

I need to refresh State multiselect based on country selected.  Any idea how to implement this in Angular 6/7.

Thanks
Shirish

Answer (score 0):

Add `ng-change="show_states()"` this to `<select>`.
And create function `show_states()`

Refer https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_events.asp

Comment: Thanks for your support.  In my case, I have change event associated with Country dropdown. This event is captured and processed successfully. In this event, I am refreshing contents of "stateControlOptions" with states for selected countries.  **But somehow it is not refreshing on UI Screen.**

Comment: Have you got solution ?